# Aligning pictures with check boxes

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Hi everyone I am having major issues not getting the check boxes next to the picture but having them in columns, two columns with the pictures with checkboxes and then one column with cehckboxes.

I know you cant see the pictures but you will get the idea

Any advice?

code

```
<div class="row">
                                  <div class="box1" style="vertical-align:top; padding-left:3px">
                                       <!-- Squared TWO -->
                                       <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="squaredTwo">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="modeler" id="squaredTwo"  name="00Nw0000004kJyc"  />
                                                    <label for="squaredTwo"></label>
                                                </div>
                                                <img src="images/check-1.jpg" alt=""> 
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="squaredTwo">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="v-modeler" id="squaredThree"  name="00Nw0000004kJyc"  />
                                                    <label for="squaredThree"></label>
                                                </div>
                                                <img src="images/check-2.jpg" alt=""> 
                                            </li>
                                       </ul> 
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class="box2" style="vertical-align:top; padding-left:15px;">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="squaredTwo">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="evolve" id="squaredfo"  name="00Nw0000004kJyc"  />
                                                    <label for="squaredfo"></label>
                                                </div>
                                                <img src="images/check-3.jpg" alt=""> 
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="squaredTwo">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="communicator" id="squaredfi"  name="00Nw0000004kJyc"  />
                                                    <label for="squaredfi"></label>
                                                </div>
                                                <img src="images/check-4.jpg" alt=""> 
                                            </li>
                                       </ul> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box3" style="padding-left:25px">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="squaredTwo">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="analytics" id="squaredsi"  name="00Nw0000004kJyc"  />
                                                    <label for="squaredsi"></label>
                                                </div>
                                                <img src="images/check-5.jpg" alt=""> 
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="squaredTwo">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="collector" id="squaredei"  name="00Nw0000004kJyc"  />
                                                    <label for="squaredei"></label>
                                                </div>
                                                <img src="images/check-6.jpg" alt=""> 
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="squaredTwo">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="synergy" id="squaredni"  name="00Nw0000004kJyc"  />
                                                    <label for="squaredni"></label>
                                                </div>
                                                <img src="images/check-7.jpg" alt=""> 
                                            </li>
                                       </ul> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the image in the div. Also make sure you close out your image tags with either `</img>` or `<img src="images/check-7.jpg" alt=""/>`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyLe6ga4/)

Answer (score 0):

I put the images in the div and put a little css behind it.

CSS:

```
.squaredTwo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Here is a js fiddle with what I found to be helpful: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqk4szws/)

**UPDATE:**
I added the checkboxes/images into two columns like your question suggested. This one also uses no css. Just a table. Here is the fiddle:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqk4szws/3/)

Comment: Thank you! The problem comes with have w separate columns. I want two of the images and check boxes in one column on top of each other and then another column to the right with two images/checkboxes on top of eachother and then the third column with 3 images/checkboxes on top of each other

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, then this new fiddle should work: http://jsfiddle.net/uqk4szws/4/